# DirectX game freeze problem using SetParent

Tags: windows, directx, freeze

The DirectX Game Freeze issue started after show the 'Run As Administrator' window.

I tried `SetWindowPos()`, `SetWindowLong()`, `ShowWindow()`, `SetForegroundWindow()`, `SetActiveWindow()` functions but don't fix the freeze problem.

All functions is working without using `SetParent()`. How to Active window handle using SetParent like `VisualBasic.interaction.AppActivate()` function?

NOT: this is not 'not responding'

[image]

Native:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Diagnostics.Process;

  //SetWindowPos Function.
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr handle, IntPtr HandleInsertAfter, int Xkoordanit, int Ykoordanit, int cxboyut, int cyboyut, uint uFlags);
 public const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
 public const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
 public const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
 // SetWindowLong Function.
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern uint SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);
 public const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
 public abstract class WindowStyles
 {
     public const uint WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000;
     public const uint WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;
     public const uint WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;
     public const uint WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
     public const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
     public const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
 }
 // ShowWindow Function
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow);
 // SetForegroundWindow Function.
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
 // SetActiveWindow
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
 // SetParent function.
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr MainWindowHandle, IntPtr Panel);
```

i tried code like focus window:

```
// form2
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); 
// dock window to form2.panel
IntPtr Handle = gameProcess.MainWindowHandle;
IntPtr Docked = SetParent(Handle, form2.panel1.handle);
// i tried all functions.
SetWindowPos(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 1024, 768, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
SetWindowPos(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0,0, 1024,768, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, (WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPED | WindowStyles.WS_CAPTION | WindowStyles.WS_SYSMENU | WindowStyles.WS_THICKFRAME | WindowStyles.WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WindowStyles.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX));
ShowWindow(Handle, 9); // ShowWindow = 9
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
Microsoft.VisualBasic.interaction.AppActivate(gameProcess.Id); // Need Microsoft.VisualBasic library DLL
SetActiveWindow(Handle);
```

Comment: Can you add some code showing what and how you are attempting things with these functions?

Comment: SetParent used like that is a hack https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683. Hacks are inpredictible.

Comment: no available window mode in game settings. so i want to make window mode. i dont think making the hack